# Change prompt colour inside midnight commander?

Tags: bash, centos, mc

I use `mc` on `CentOS9`. It has its own prompt on the bottom under the panels. I dont know if it is a separate bash or some sort of emulation, but it has default colour while "normal" prompt is coloured.

**I want to change the mc prompt colour.** How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make the prompt colorized.

But `mc` has an ability to change color themes, look in Options/Appearance. There are many themes already exist and you can choose one you like the most. Or create your own.

Read here on how to create one:
https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/doc/common/skins

Comment: yeah i know but it doesnt change the prompt colour much.. its still some shade of gray